Firestore's inequality filter index inconsistency
From Firestore documentation, under Index Modes, its states that both ascending and descending single field indexes support any inequality filters.
Index types in Cloud Firestore
Say I have 2 collections named "Subjects" and "Courses":
I have disabled all automatic single field indexes, then added the following:

Collection: "Subjects", Field: last_updated ascending


Collection: "Courses", Field: last_updated descending

When I query:

collection("Subjects").where(last_updated, isGreaterThan, someDate)
collection("Courses").where(last_updated, isGreaterThan, someDate)

First query succeeds, second fails.
The second is fixed by applying the following:

collection("Courses").where(last_updated, isGreaterThan, someDate)
.orderBy(last_updated, descending: True)

It is an easy fix, but i want to understand the behaviour. Why it worked for one collection but not the other. I have tried both queries from Firebase IOS SDK and Firestore's query builder from the console, all to the same result.

That seems odd, but we're probably not seeing the complete picture. Please edit your question to show the exact, complete code we can all run standalone to reproduce the problem. So a query that works, and a query that doesn't - in  a format where we can pretty much copy/paste and run it to get the problem. --- I recommend reading How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example too, as following the advice there drastically increases the chances that someone can help.

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.
